# FilePond - Method that tells you if a file has been uploaded

Tags: angular, filepond

Is there a method within filepond that will return true if a File is uploaded?  If not, is there another way to tell if a file is uploaded?  I'll provide sample code below:

```
if(this.filepond.<method>){
     this.filepond.processFile().then(file => {});
}
```

I am also using this in a angular application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I was needing by doing the following:

```
 this.filepond.processFile().then(file => {
       console.log('Add code when a file is processed');

 }).catch(file => {
       console.log('Add code when file is not uploaded');
 });
```